# JOOQ batch update dates with Oracle 11g

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, jooq

While I’m trying to batch update a field in a Oracle 11g table with Jooq 3.9.0, and I’m getting date related exceptions:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [null]; error occurred during batching: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

We’re using Java 8 time types (`javaTimeTypes = true`). Pseudo code:

```
List<Query> updates = singletonList(
        jooq.update(TABLE).set(TABLE.FIELD, LocalDateTime.now()));
jooq.batch(updates).execute();
```

The field has TIMESTAMP(3) type in the table.
So far I’ve tried to do non-batch updates, e.g.:

```
updates.forEach(Query::execute);
```

this works, but I wouldn’t sacrifice performance unless it’s absolutely necessary.

Also tried to add a type binding in Jooq’s config which wraps date fields in a `to_timestamp(<Val>, “pattern”)` call, that also worked, but it seems to be fragile, already raised NLS issues and it looks ugly. Would be nice to figure out why batch updates behaving differently compared to regular ones.

Comment: Can you see the SQL generated in the log? (note I've also opened an issue for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5910)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ran into this issue here: [#2738](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2738), which is fixed for 3.10 and will be integrated [in 3.9.2](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5778).

Since you're using batch updates with the [`batch(Collection)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batch-java.util.Collection-) API for static statement batches, the bind variables need to be inlined, which doesn't work correctly for Java time API types in jOOQ 3.9.1

Comment: Yes that's the issue we're facing, thanks for the feedback -- sorry about the delay.